# Who is the blond woman in Blame?

Tags: blame

I haven't been able to figure out who this character is; I don't think they mention her name during the movie at all.  I find it kinda strange because she is a pretty prominent character.  Does she appear in the manga?  I haven't read any of it.

[image]

Comment: In the manga, does not appear, at least in the same way she did in the movie, there are lots of electric fishers but not everyone is named.
So she perhaps appeared but not named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this site (https://www.anisearch.com/anime/10968,blame/characters) her name is Fuku. Is the only info I found about her.
T